# Is it possible to get a Google Scholar search results which excludes any article/paper which is stored in the personal library of Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

Is it possible to get a Google Scholar search results which excludes any article/paper which is stored in the personal library of Google Scholar?

"So for example: to get any results I haven't looked into yet/saved for later..."

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get a Google Scholar search results which excludes any article/paper which is stored in the personal library of Google Scholar?

Not possible, unfortunately. The advanced search doesn't have this feature:

[image]

Settings don't have this option either.